# TypeScript code keeps appearing after router change requests

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I have an Angular project where one of the pages contain:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    let button: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('button#changeDir') as HTMLElement
    ...
})
```

When I try to change the directory using `@angular/router` and resize the window, I get the error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
```

I've tried to make an if statement

```
if (this.router.url == "\") ...
```

But if you go back to that page using `@angular/router` without refreshing it just adds on to the workload causing the page act slower. Is there a way to ignore the code that was enacted after/during the change of directories?

Comment: If the button is part of an angular template, your code is wrong

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say it's Angular9

Comment: pls post router navigation code too or even better create stackblitz

Comment: What makes you think the button is guaranteed to exist when the window is resized?

Answer (score 0):

After researching for a bit I found an alternative to `addEventListener` that would not be enacted after the route change with `@angular/router`:

1. Create the function in TypeScript that would execute on window resize:

```
onWindowResizeFun() {
    let button: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('button#changeDir') as HTMLElement
    ...
}
```

2. Add to one of the HTML elements (better to the most parent element):

```
<section (window:resize)="onWindowResizeFun()">
```